# Regarding precision and recall

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

Suppose we have 99% non-span and 1% span. Here I have written function as below

```
function y = predictSpam(x)

y = 0;

return
```

here we have true positive's are zero. And accuracy is 99%. In this case precision and recall is zero. Is my understanding is right? Request to provide to fill in below table in case of below scenario

```
                  actualclass1  | actualclass0

predict class1         0         |  0
-------------------------------------------------
predict class0         1         |  99
```

m = 100. Is above table is filled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When using precision and recall I quite always look again this image:
[image: Precision & Recall]

So we have:

`precision = true_positive / true_positive + false_positive
recall = true_positive / true_positive + false_negative`

In your data, 99 is correctly classified 0, 1 is classified 0 when it should be 1.

With your data:
- `true_positive = 0`
- `true_negative = 99`
- `false_positive = 0`
- `false_negative = 1`

Your true positive is 0, so yes, both recall and precision will be 0.

Accuracy is indeed 99%.